# Api Google Adwords How we can get report for a one campaign during the current month but per day?

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

i need to generate the report using the api google adwords , for just one campain , during the current month but per each day , here is my query :

```
  $reportQuery = 'SELECT CampaignId,CampaignName, Impressions, Clicks, Cost '
        . ' FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT '
        . ' WHERE CampaignId = '.$campaignId.' DURING this_month';
```

i would like to get the result in this format :

```
date | impressions | clicks | ...
01/11| 12356785    | 23561  | ...
02/11| 23567985    | 3561   | ...
03/11| 82356785    | 56892  | ...
04/11| 62356785    | 562234 | ...
```

Is it possible ? if not how we can get the report without downloading the file ?
Thanks

Comment: What does your query currently generate? How is it different from what you want? You likely need to group your query by date.

Comment: thanks for your response , how can i group it by date and show this date too? my current query show the sum of all the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `Date` field to your query should do the trick. As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report#date), `Date` has "Segment" behavior, so it will give you a new line with all the other metrics for every single one of its own values.